# Spring Boot Kotlin Google OAuth 2.0 Logout Getting CORS Error

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, google-oauth

I am writing a full-stack application:

- Backend in Spring Boot 3 / Kotlin
- Frontend in Angular 16

The application uses Google OAuth2 authentication tokens. I have deployed my application to a droplet on the hosting service DigitalOcean. The machine is running CentOS 9 and the application is running using docker and docker-compose.

Logging in works fine, I am redirected to the Google sign-in page and upon successful authentication, I am redirected back to the application's home page with a newly attained session cookie.

However, when I try to log out, it seems to work at first as I am prompted by the Spring Security logout page to click the button to log out, but when I click logout, I get the following response:

```
Invalid CORS request
```

This is my production profile security config class with CORS configured:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Profile("production")
class SecurityProductionConfig(
    private val clientRegistrationRepository: ClientRegistrationRepository
) {

    @Value("\${sparrow.environment.frontEndHost}")
    private lateinit var frontEndHost: String

    @Value("\${sparrow.environment.googleLoginHost}")
    private lateinit var googleLoginHost: String

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .and()
            .cors { httpSecurityCorsConfigurer: CorsConfigurer<HttpSecurity?> ->
                httpSecurityCorsConfigurer.configurationSource(
                    urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()
                )
            }
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/logout-success")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login { httpSecurityOAuth2LoginConfigurer: OAuth2LoginConfigurer<HttpSecurity?> ->
                httpSecurityOAuth2LoginConfigurer.defaultSuccessUrl(
                    "$frontEndHost/login-success",
                    true
                )
            }
            .logout { httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer: LogoutConfigurer<HttpSecurity?> ->
                httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer.logoutSuccessUrl("$frontEndHost/logout-success")
                httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer.logoutSuccessHandler(
                    oidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler()
                )
                httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer.invalidateHttpSession(true)
                httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer.clearAuthentication(true)
                httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer.deleteCookies(COOKIE_NAME_TO_CLEAR)
                httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer.permitAll()
            }
        return http.build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun corsFilter(): CorsFilter {
        return CorsFilter(urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource())
    }

    @Bean
    fun corsConfigurer(): WebMvcConfigurer {
        val allowedDomains = arrayOf(frontEndHost, googleLoginHost)
        return object : WebMvcConfigurer {
            override fun addCorsMappings(@NonNull registry: CorsRegistry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins(*allowedDomains)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource(): UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource {
        val corsConfiguration = CorsConfiguration()
        corsConfiguration.allowCredentials = true
        corsConfiguration.allowedOrigins =
            listOf(frontEndHost, googleLoginHost)
        corsConfiguration.allowedHeaders = listOf(
            "Origin",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "Content-Type",
            "Accepts",
            "Authorization",
            "Origin, Accept",
            "X-Requested-With",
            "Access-Control-Request-Method",
            "Access-Control-Request-Headers"
        )
        corsConfiguration.exposedHeaders = listOf(
            "Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"
        )
        corsConfiguration.allowedMethods =
            listOf("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
        val urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource = UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()
        urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration)
        return urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource
    }

    private fun oidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler(): OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler {
        val successHandler = OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler(
            clientRegistrationRepository
        )
        successHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("$frontEndHost/logout-success")
        return successHandler
    }

    companion object {
        private const val COOKIE_NAME_TO_CLEAR = "JSESSIONID"
    }

}
```

I have tested this configuration locally, redirecting back to the API running on my machine but I don't see the same behavior on the remote server, I only see the CORS response.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not find a solution in this case. I have since migrated to use Spring Cloud Gateway and no longer experience such issues.